# Horizontal Scroll bar on site not showing up

Tags: php, html, css

There are some similar posts about this but I couldn't seem to figure it out based on them.  I just built a new homepage for our site, but the horizontal scroll bar isn't showing up for some reason.  Works on all the other pages.  Anyone have any idea why? 
http://ghcnow.com/index2.php

Thanks!

Here is an overview of the code layout

```
<html style="overflow:hidden;">
<head></head>
<body>
   <div id="content">
      <div class="container2">
         <div class="fullwidthbanner-container" style="width: 100% !important; overflow: hidden; position: relative; padding: 0; max-height: 500px !important;">/*stuff in here*/
         </div>
         <div class="container" style="width: 1030px; margin: 0 auto;">/*stuff in here*/
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the scroll bar to show up only if someone's window is smaller than the 1030px of the container div.  If I take the overflow:hidden; out of the html, the scroll bar shows up like everyone says.  However, the min-width did not work on the body as suggested because of something to do with the fullwidthbanner-container div.

Comment: Please post examples of your code. Adding a link to an existing site isn't sufficient here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `overflow: hidden` for your `html` tag.

But you definitely should consider using a more flexible layout. Horizontal scrollbars are never a good thing.

Comment: First, let me thank everyone for their comments.  I agree with you Linus and also with you Thakur.  I don't understand the basic concept that generates the scroll bar.  I would like it only to show if the window is smaller than my #content div. It is this way on all of my other pages, but there is something on the homepage that is making it act different.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You style your `<body/>` with `min-width: 1250px;` which means, that with i.e. `overflow: auto` set you'll get scrollbars as soon as the window width is below 1250 pixels.

Comment: Hi Linus, thanks for the response. If I turn overflow:hidden off for my html tag, it always shows the scroll bar. When I added the code above mentioned to the body tag, the scroll bar is still always on there.  I think it may have something to do with the fullwidthbanner-container div, but I can't seem to put my finger on it. Any thoughts?

Comment: No, it's because of the `border-left-width` and `border-right-width` of the `.tickercontainer`. Remove those or set them to 0.

Comment: Ah, thank you thank you thank you! So you were correct with the `overflow:hidden` on the `html` tag.  The thing that was making the scroll bar show up no matter what, was that I had left and right borders on the `.tickercontainer` div (which spanned the width of the page).  I changed the css to just top and bottom borders and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

On your **CSS** change this

```
html {
    overflow-x:hidden;
    padding: 0 !important;
    /*background-image:url(images/tiles/bgtile.png);*/
    margin:0px !important;
}
```

to

```
html {
    padding: 0 !important;
    /*background-image:url(images/tiles/bgtile.png);*/
    margin:0px !important;
}
```

Just remove `overflow-x: hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Meh, Just remove `overflow-x:hidden`. That's all. Enjoy your HTML.
But hey! I would rather prefer NOT having a horizontal scroll bar on my site. That looks ridiculous.
Sincerely,
Thakur Saksham Chauhan

Answer (score 0):

When you use `overflow: hidden;` in your body or html, CSS file you have to refer the axis means: `overflow-x: hidden;` in this case y axis stay with the scroll bar :)